# Executable error : Can't start program

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, codeblocks, libcurl

After finishing my C++ program (on windows os using codeblocks)(using libcurl) when i try to launch the program from the executable it displays an error saying that i can't start the program because libcurldll is missing,reinstall program then retry. I don't think any line of code is needed here,it's just a configuration and logics problem,any ideas,would be great !

Please note that,running it from the codeblocks's console works fine.

Comment: 1) Find the `libcurldll` file.  2) Find the folder containing your executable. 3) Copy the `libcurldll` file into the folder containing your executable.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews well thanks,it worked fine for me(if you post this comment as an answer i can pick as being the answer to this question).
Though,This problems persists when i try to use the programm on other computers,and the solution is still the same as here,and i dont want this to happen,is there any way i could include those dlls into the program?so i could have only one executable at the end?
if not,is there any other library that could help me achieve my program(sends emails via smtp using libcurl) without having this dlls problem?

Comment: Search the internet for "DLL Hell" as background information.  The solution for other computers is to use an Installer application and have the Installer put the DLLs (that are used by your application) in the same folder as your application, if possible.  You may want to search the documentation of your IDE on how to inform the executable where the DLLs are located.  You can also "delay load" or have the executable load the DLLs.

Comment: I will look it up,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common issue with DLLs or SOs is that the executable needs to know where they are.

A common solution is to place the DLL library in the same folder as the executable:

1. Find the `libcurldll` file.
2. Find the folder containing your executable.
3. Copy the `libcurldll` file into the folder containing your executable.